# Does First Strike apply when two creatures Fight each other?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does First Strike apply when two creatures fight, i.e when they have been targets of the Fight ability?

Answer (score 5):

**No.** First strike only works in combat, and Fight is not a combat ability. See the [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020181005.txt):

> 701.12. Fight
>
> 701.12a A spell or ability may instruct a creature to fight another creature or it may instruct two creatures to fight each other. Each of those creatures deals damage equal to its power to the other creature.
>
> 701.12b If a creature instructed to fight is no longer on the battlefield or is no longer a creature, no damage is dealt. If a creature is an illegal target for a resolving spell or ability that instructs it to fight, no damage is dealt.
>
> 701.12c If a creature fights itself, it deals damage to itself equal to twice its power.
>
> 701.12d The damage dealt when a creature fights isn’t combat damage.

> 702.7. First Strike
>
> 702.7a First strike is a static ability that modifies the rules for the combat damage step. (See rule 510, “Combat Damage Step.”)

Comment: And even if first strike did matter, the damage would still be dealt during a single resolution, and creatures don't have an opportunity to die from lethal damage until after the spell has resolved. I can't imagine there are many edges case where it matters whether the damage is dealt simultaneously or one after the other.